# Stay of Eviction - Special Civil Court Case transferred to Civil

Tags: landlord, tenant, rent, eviction, civil

I am defending myself (pro se) for which I have a tenant owing me back rent.  I had filed for eviction via Special civil court, but due to another case pending from the complaint filed by the tenant against me as the defendant, a judge transferred the case subject to the entire controversy doctrine to combine related cases in the same court in NJ. My question is as follows:  does a stay of eviction allow the tenants to stop paying rent pending the resolution of the civil case?  I am considering calling the court and having the question posed to the judge that made the order.